# How to add or remove class based on window width automatically

Tags: javascript, window, width, real-time

I have this piece of code. This code works well but a page reload is necessary. How can I make the same effect but in real time without reloading the page?

```
if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
  $('.close-btn').click(function () {
    $('.side-bar').addClass('non-active');
    $('.menu-btn').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });

  $('.menu-btn').click(function () {
    $('.side-bar').removeClass('non-active');
    $('.menu-btn').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
} else {
  $('.side-bar').addClass('non-active');
  $('.menu-btn').click(function () {
    $('.side-bar').removeClass('non-active');
    $('.menu-btn').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
  $('.close-btn').click(function () {
    $('.side-bar').addClass('non-active');
    $('.menu-btn').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Window `resize` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)

Try executing the code in response to a `resize` event being fired on the `window` object.

Given `resize` events can be generated rapidly, it is common practice to filter responding to them as much as possible. In this case, no action need be taken until window width crosses the 850px boundary. Presumably the first branch is for wide screen presentation, so something like

```js
const resizeHandler = (function() {
  // record current side of boundary: 
  const isBig = ()=>window.innerWidth > 850;
  let wasBig  = isBig();

  return function handler(event) {
    if( isBig() == wasBig) return; // no change
    if (!wasBig) {
      // posted code:
      $('.close-btn').click(function () {
        $('.side-bar').addClass('non-active');
        $('.menu-btn').css('visibility', 'visible');
      });
      
      $('.menu-btn').click(function () {
        $('.side-bar').removeClass('non-active');
        $('.menu-btn').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });
      wasBig = true; // future use
    }
    else { 
      // posted code:
      $('.side-bar').addClass('non-active');
      $('.menu-btn').click(function () {
        $('.side-bar').removeClass('non-active');
        $('.menu-btn').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });
      $('.close-btn').click(function () {
        $('.side-bar').addClass('non-active');
        $('.menu-btn').css('visibility', 'visible');
      });
      wasBig = false;
    } 
  };
})();
window.addEventListener ("resize", resizeHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to prevent the click event's default behavior onClick if the page is reloading. Do this for each click event on a button.

Something like:
`$('.close-btn').click(function (e) {e.preventDefault()}`

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: How does this answer the question of how to make the page responsive _without_ reloading it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation yet to comment, on traktor's response, but I agree with their answer. One thing to consider is the toggle behavior is duplicated in two different parts of the code. One part when the window size is bigger than 850px and one part when it's less than or equal to 850px. Instead of having two copies, it might be cleaner to put the toggle behavior in a single function and use the "wasBig" state to decide which toggle behavior to use.